# Passing all arbitrary attributes from html definition to a template element

Tags: angularjs

I'm making a number of form directives with angular to reuse and I'd like to pass all attributes put on my directive to the input tag in my template.

So if they wrote:

```
<jays-input required class="well"></jays-input>
```

Even though my directive doesn't formally take the attributes required or class, it would transfer them to the "input" part of my template. So my template would be something like:

```
<input placeholder="jays input" {{$all_attributes}} />
```

...Where $all_attributes would be 'required class="well"'. Even better would be just the attributes that don't match what the directive expects.

While writing this I realized I could just parse the $attrs array my self, but I wonder if there is a shorthand or something. I feel like it would be common to make a directive that merely wraps html around a specific element and in that case you'd want to transfer all attributes to the focal element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your directive definition's compile function, add the attributes using jQuery:

```
app.directive('jaysInput', function() {
     return  {
        restrict: 'E',
        compile: function(element, attr) {
            $('input', element).each(function(){
               for (var i in attr) 
               {
                   $(this).attr(i, attr[i]);
               }
           }
           return function(scope, element, attr) {
               // return link function
           };
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: This is a good enough answer :). Barring any built in feature in Angular, this seems like the best method.